What is a MinIO Access key and how does it work?
I have read the documentation, asked GPT and also read the corresponding mc command doc and I don't get what a Access Key is.
It doesn't help that the documentation uses access key also as username (for example in the mc command it says
USER
Required
The username of the user to which MinIO adds the new access key.

    For MinIO-managed users, specify the access key for the user.

So to "set an access key" I need to "specify the access key"! <--I guess the second one refers to the user name but still...
So can someone tell me what an access key is, and in what cases can I use it and how?
It is worth noticing that the docs say

Access Keys are for Programmatic Access
Access Keys support
programmatic access by applications. You cannot use an access key to
log into the MinIO Console.

